# Pandas: filtering with mix of string and null

Tags: pandas, filter, null

Given a DataFrame, how can I filter to get a new DataFrame, based on:

YYYYMM, category, type, sub_type

Where sub_type can contain None, and the filter criteria might be None. Seem to be having issues creating something that works for both cases. I did it in two steps, with

```
if sub_type is None     
   df = df[pd.isna(df["sub_type"])]
else:
   df = df[(df["sub_type"] == workflow_sub_type)]
```

If this gets more complicated, I don't want too many if/elses... Can I do this in one step?

```
    action  category   YYYYMM      timestamp      sub_type       type 
0     buy      A       202002           4            None        apple 
1     sell     A       202002           5            None        apple 
2     buy      A       202002           4            green       apple 
3     buy      A       202002           4            red         apple 
4     sell     A       202002           3            red         apple 
5     sell     A       202002           1            None        orange
6     sell     B       202002           6            None        apple
```

Comment: what is the expected output. I assume the data you shared is the source dataframe?

Comment: no this is mock data for the question...
The idea is I have a function with the values to filter on for the 3 columns - which the caller can pass in a str or None

Comment: the UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
was a typo - just fixed it - referenced the orig dataframe, prior to the first filter ( I broke out this if/else as a 2nd filter), so the index/size was different...

still... can this be done in a single statement? or is this readable/acceptable

Comment: what he means is, is this the mock input or mock output? please include both the input and desired output.